# The reason of Tiltul in Shabbath

Tags: halacha, shabbat, melacha-creative-work, taamei-mitzvot-reasons

I remember to have studied a Tosefot where it is written that it is very hard to understand why is forbidden to transport something on Shabbath (Tiltul).
Somebody can tell me where is this Tosefot

Comment: Isn't it the first one?

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Tosafot_on_Shabbat.2a.4.1?lang=bi?

Comment: @Joel K , thanks a lot!